# Is showGroupPanel option available in Angular js ui-grid similar to ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

Does Angular js ui-grid have showGroupPanel option available similar to ng-grid.
If not then is there any other way to implement this feature in ui-grid?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the ui-grid directive: [uiGridGrouping](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.grouping.directive:uiGridGrouping)